# Improving Scroll Speed During Virtualization

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a Datagrid as shown in the code below that has a bunch of DataGridColumns.
The issue is that I need to display over 1000 rows with around 10 columns along with grouping based on the selected column.

When I enable virtualization the speed at which the palette opens improves but when I expand a column that's large the scrolling functionality slows down a huge amount.

I've read that this is just a recurring issue in WPF but I wanted to see if anyone has an elegant workaround since my application requires the scroll speed to not be that slow.

When I remove virtualization the scrolling works fine but the opening of the palette becomes extremely slow along with anything that requires the palette to regenerate.

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dg"
              MaxWidth="2560"
              MaxHeight="1600"
              Height="500"    
              Width="{Binding 
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel}, Path=ActualWidth}"              
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserAddRows="false"
              CanUserSortColumns="True"
              PreparingCellForEdit="dg_PreparingCellForEdit"
              CellEditEnding="dg_CellEditEnding"
              SelectionMode="Extended"
              AllowDrop="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding PointsData, IsAsync=True}"
              PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="dg_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown"
              PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="dg_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
              MouseMove="dg_MouseMove"
              Drop="dg_Drop"
              Loaded="dg_Loaded"
              self:DataGridSortBehavior.AllowCustomSort="True"
              SelectionChanged="dg_SelectionChanged"
              VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
              EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
              EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
      <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
          <GroupStyle.Panel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </GroupStyle.Panel>
          <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
              <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Expander IsExpanded="False" Background="LightGray" Foreground="Black">
                      <ItemsPresenter Visibility="{Binding ElementName=exp, Path=IsExpanded, Converter={StaticResource bool2vis}}" />
                      <Expander.Header>
                        <TextBlock>
                          <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource expHeaderConv}" Mode="TwoWay">
                              <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=UserControl}"/>
                              <Binding />
                            </MultiBinding>
                          </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                      </Expander.Header>
                    </Expander>
                  </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
            </Style>
          </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
      </DataGrid.GroupStyle>

      <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
          <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDuplicate}" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```